# significant change in predicted score distribution when scaling using glmnet

Tags: r, scale, glmnet

I'm struggling to understand the predict function, or perhaps the effects of scaling.
Below i show my coding procedure to train a logistic regression model using GLMNET with: 1)no scaling, and 2) with scaling.  I make no change to anything else, yet i get wildy different output score distributions from the predict function using type "response".
The model performances are very similar (e.g. very similar ROC-AUC)

Can someone help me understand why the distributions are so different? does it have something to do with the scaling and/or type "response"?

Notably! when i remove "intercept=FALSE" , both distributions then match the left skewed distribution (e.g the first plot below).  Why would this make them match?

Overall, how can i interpret these scores (e.g what does type  "response" output?)
additionally, the outcome prediction proportions are:
   0= 2569 1 = 427

```
modeldata = dm
#define binary outcome variable
y =modeldata$BinaryOutcome
#remove outcome from the predictor set
modeldata = as.data.frame(subset(modeldata,select = -c(BinaryOutcome) ))
#scale the variables (here we DO NOT scale)
#modeldata[ind] <- lapply(modeldata[ind], scale)
#format as matrix
x_test =  as.matrix(modeldata)
#fit the model using glmnet
cvfit = cv.glmnet(x_test, y,
                  intercept=FALSE ,
                  family =   "binomial", alpha=1, nfolds=5)

#score and plot the score histograms
best_lambda = cvfit$lambda[which.min(cvfit$cvm)]
model_scores = predict(cvfit, x_test, s = best_lambda,type= "response")
hist(model_scores,breaks=100)


# run again but with scaling ----------------------------------------------
modeldata = dm
#define binary outcome variable
y =modeldata$BinaryOutcome
#remove outcome from the predictor set
modeldata = as.data.frame(subset(modeldata,select = -c(BinaryOutcome) ))
#scale the variables (here we DO scale)
modeldata = sapply(modeldata, scale)
#format as matrix
x_test =  as.matrix(modeldata)
#fit the model using glmnet
cvfit = cv.glmnet(x_test, y,
                  intercept=FALSE ,
                  family =   "binomial", alpha=1, nfolds=5)
#score and plot the score histograms
best_lambda = cvfit$lambda[which.min(cvfit$cvm)]
model_scores_scaled = predict(cvfit, x_test, s = best_lambda,type= "response")
hist(model_scores_scaled,breaks=100)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: (a) I don't get what's going on; the intercept note is especially confusing, but (b) you should pretty much always scale your inputs for the LASSO, unless all your data is on the same scale already. (c) `glmnet` does this by default. From `?glmnet`, the `standardize` argument says *"Logical flag for x variable standardization, prior to fitting the model sequence. The coefficients are always returned on the original scale. Default is `standardize=TRUE`"*. So I think you should try again with `standardize = FALSE` if you want to compare standardized vs not, and maybe let `glmnet` handle it.

Comment: Lastly, a minor comment that `modeldata = as.data.frame(subset(modeldata,select = -c(BinaryOutcome) ))` is a long way to write `modeldata$BinaryOutcome = NULL` At the very least, delete the `as.data.frame()`.

Comment: Thanks for the note.  Here's my question more summarized:  I get very different distributions on the predictive scores depending on if i scale the data or I don't, prior to running it in the glmnet (e.g. the predicted score histograms).  This difference goes away, if I change intercept=FALSE , to TRUE.  Why does this happen?